# Script to store name of selected object / curve, so that I can select again

Tags: scripting, bezier-curves

I'm looking for a way to store selected object / curve name so that I can reference it in a script.

The idea is to select a curve (with the mouse), then copy another object to its location(with a script). I would also need to reference the original object so I can fill in some modifiers. Problems I'm having now: In order to duplicate that "other" object, I need to select it... which causes me to lose focus from the currently selected original object.

rough code is...

```
bpy.context.selected_objects 

bpy.data.objects['OBJ1'].select = True #select an already created object

bpy.ops.object.duplicate() #duplicate OBJ1

# move duplicated object to same place as originally selected.
# figure out a way to copy location info from original selection.
bpy.data.objects.new.location 

bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='ARRAY')
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Array"].fit_type = 'FIT_CURVE'

#curvename would be the original thing selected
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Array"].curve = bpy.data.objects[curveName]
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You can add modifiers without the ops with eg http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58676/add-modifier-to-selected-and-another-to-active-object/58683#58683  Also you can dupe an object with `ob = obj.copy()` and then link it to scene with `scene.objects.link(ob)`    Oh and btw to get code formatting indent all lines of code by 4 spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Aye, that's just some place holder code. Main problem I'm having is referencing the originally selected object. Is there a way to store it's name and then bring focus back to it. I've only really needed to bpy.context.selected_objects and bpy.context.active_object, in the past... so this is a bit more difficult for me.

Comment: Plain and simple `curve = context.active_object` Then after dupe or other operators that change the active object  `dupe = context.active_object` after which curve will still refer to the curve that was the active object when you assigned it.  To set the active context object back to curve use `scene.objects.active = curve`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to store the object by doing:

```
object1 = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
```

then you can use:

```
object2.location = object1.location
```

to set object2's location to be the same as object1's location.

Answer (score 1):

for the selection part of things: Why not simply make the user select both items in a specific order? Blender stores the objects in selection order in this property:

```
bpy.context.selected_objects
```

That means, if you first select a cube, then a sphere, then a circle, the property content will be:

```
[bpy.data.objects['Cube'], bpy.data.objects['Sphere'], bpy.data.objects['Circle']]
```

To access them, you could use the index:

```
bpy.context.selected_objects[0]  # = first selected object
bpy.context.selected_objects[1]  # = second selected object
bpy.context.selected_objects[-1]  # = last selected object
```

Also, the last selected object will be the active one:

```
bpy.context.active_object
```