# Apply modifiers in all objects at once

Tags: modifiers

Let's say I have LEGO model in Blender containing 1000 bricks (objects) and every single one has its own modifiers - is there a way how to apply all of them (well, I mean those objects that are selected) at once, so that I would not need to go manually all of those 1000 objects one by one?

Possibly rather in a form of simple addon instead of script so one could just click a single button everytime he needs?

Comment: There isn't an addon specifically for this (while you could save the script as your own one for faster running). As far as I know, Ctrl+A > Visual Geometry to Mesh applies all modifiers but hidden ones on selected objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nearly [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76828/how-to-apply-a-specific-modifier-on-selected-objects?rq=1).

For all modifiers you can run this script that will apply them all:

```
import bpy

for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
    for name in [m.name for m in ob.modifiers]:
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply( modifier = name )
```

To run the script:

open a text editor, create a new text, paste the code above, select the wanted objects, and use the button indicated in the picture below:

[image]

If you want to apply modifier that are visible in viewport only, use this:

```
import bpy

for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
    for name in [m.name for m in ob.modifiers]:
        modifier = ob.modifiers[name]
        if modifier.show_viewport:
            bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply( modifier = name )
```

Comment: Sorry to ask but how to run a script in Blender, please?

Comment: Edited for some explaination. If not clear ask here

Comment: great - it works, but I would like to apply only ALLOWED modifiers, not all of them one object can have (you know those, that are there, but are inactive), maybe even remove those that are inactive (if possible)?

Comment: Inactive in viewport, render, both?

Comment: I do not render in Blender, I am using Blender just as export tool to FBX for UE4, so probably viewport only? :-) Also I am thinking about making it into extremely simlpe addon, like single button, so I would just click it without going thru text Editor, Open Script, press Apply with every other model I would have - is it possible?

Comment: This is possible but above the scope of your question. Will update for viewport enable.

Comment: I just updated the scope of my question a little bit... :-)

Comment: Well... not for me (you should work a bit by yourself... have a look to Blender provided templates in the text editor)... but fortunatley, someone else will answer.

Comment: Actually, I am just watching one such tutorial, thank you - your script works now just fine, except it does not remove those inactive modifiers (tho at least it ignores them)

Comment: Last thing: can you modify the script so that it would actually remove those inactive modifiers instead of omitting them during apply process (if possible, of course)?