# Apply only one type of modifier on multiple objects at once

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror

I have a multiple objects with many modifiers. Most of them have mirror modifier. Can I somehow select all the object and apply all mirror modifiers? Iam aware that there is a button to apply all modifiers, however, I would like only the mirror modifiers to be applied and the rest of it stayed intact.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/76875/31447 Just replace `'ARMATURE'` by `'MIRROR'`.

Comment: Iam not familiar with scripting, but if all I have to do is copy it to editor type, change armature to mirror and then run the script, then it does not work.

Comment: No issues here, works like a charm. Head over to the scripting workspace, copy and paste the code by lemon for 2.8+ into a new text document, replace `'ARMATURE'` by `'MIRROR'`. Select all objects, run the script, done. Works, doesn't it?

Comment: Yep, sorry. The problem was between chair and keyboard

Comment: You cannot do that if the mirror modifiers are not on the top. Blender apply the modifier on top if you are not select first modifier.

Comment: modifier tools addon comes with blender it can help you maybe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kaiBJMZkInQ

Answer (score 2):

You can try to apply once to one object then use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to redo the last action while selecting the other objects. It's still one by one but faster.