# How would I make a pluggin to toggle subd surfaces on and off and add the sub modifier to the stack?

Tags: python, scripting

I was wondering how I would be able to script a plugin that would toggle subd surfaces preview if it has a sudb modifier on. It would also be helpful that if the selected object doesn't have a subd modifier in the stack already, it would add one and then toggle the subd view.

Maya allows you to toggle between subd view through the 1 and 3 key and thought this would be really neat to have in Blender but also the addition to add the modifier if it doesn't already have one on. I just don't know how to script and was wondering if anyone has already done this or not.

Comment: and for adding the new modifier
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71569/how-to-add-modifiers-using-python-script-and-set-parameters
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58676/add-modifier-to-selected-and-another-to-active-object

Comment: Just adding a sidenote: in Maya you can't see your base mesh when modeling with subsurface ON, but in Blender you can, which is why there is no need for a quick way to toggle subdiv on and off when modeling as you can clearly see both meshs at all time.