# Repeteadly calling one modifier upon other

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

I am trying to run `shrinkwrap` and then `remesh modifier` repeatedly but not working. It seems to me there is a **infinite loop** inside the code. I am new to blender and python coding. What is wrong with that code?

I am using Blender 3.6

```
import bpy

jaw = bpy.data.objects['jaw']

for i in range(0,20):
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SHRINKWRAP')
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Shrinkwrap"].target = jaw
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Shrinkwrap"].offset = 0.5

    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='REMESH')
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Remesh"].mode = 'SMOOTH'
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Remesh"].use_remove_disconnected = False
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Remesh"].octree_depth = 8

    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier='SHRINKWRAP')
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier='REMESH')
```

Comment: This is [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Please specify what you are trying to accomplish, why would you want to add the modifier 20 times?

Comment: There is no infinite loop, the code is ok. Depending on the complexity of your mesh, it just may take a while to perform. Even for two simple cubes it takes some seconds. Add a `print(i)` statement in the loop to observe this in the system console. As @HarryMcKenzie already asked, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="modifier_name")`

takes actual modifier name, which is unique for every modifier.
What you are passing is modifier type.

[Add modifier to selected and another to active object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58676/add-modifier-to-selected-and-another-to-active-object)

See the above link.

In your specific case, you can get away using

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier='Shrinkwrap')
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier='Remesh')
```

As new modifiers are named that way.